# How to load 2D array from a text(csv) file into Octave?

Tags: file-io, csv, octave, text-files

Consider the following text(csv) file:

```
1, Some text
2, More text
3, Text with comma, more text
```

How to load the data into a 2D array in Octave? The number can go into the first column, and all text to the right of the first comma (including other commas) goes into the second text column.

If necessary, I can replace the first comma with a different delimiter character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many long hours of searching and debugging, here's how I got it to work on Octave 3.2.4. Using `|` as the delimiter (instead of comma).

The data file now looks like:

```
1|Some text
2|More text
3|Text with comma, more text
```

Here's how to call it: `data = load_data('data/data_file.csv', NUMBER_OF_LINES);`

Limitation: You need to know how many lines you want to get. If you want to get ***all***, then you will need to write a function to count the number of lines in the file in order to initialize the cell_array. It's all very clunky and primitive. So much for "high level languages like Octave".

Note: After the unpleasant exercise of getting this to work, it seems that Octave is not very useful unless you enjoy wasting your time writing code to do the simplest things. Better choices seems to be R, Python, or C#/Java with a Machine Learning or Matrix library.

```
function all_messages = load_data(filename, NUMBER_OF_LINES)
  fid = fopen(filename, "r");

  all_messages = cell (NUMBER_OF_LINES, 2 );
  counter = 1;

  line = fgetl(fid);

  while line != -1
      separator_index = index(line, '|');
      all_messages {counter, 1} = substr(line, 1, separator_index - 1); % Up to the separator
      all_messages {counter, 2} = substr(line, separator_index + 1, length(line) - separator_index); % After the separator
      counter++;

      line = fgetl(fid);
  endwhile

  fprintf("Processed %i lines.\n", counter -1);
  fclose(fid);
end
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK you cannot put stings of different size into an array. You need to create a so called [cell array](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Cell-Arrays.html#Cell-Arrays).

A possible way to read the data from your question stored in a file *Test.txt* into a cell array is

```
t1 = textread("Test.txt", "%s", "delimiter", "\n");
for i = 1:length(t1)
    j = findstr(t1{i}, ",")(1);
    T{i,1} = t1{i}(1:j - 1);
    T{i,2} = strtrim(t1{i}(j + 1:end));
end
```

Now
`T{3,1}` gives you `3` and
`T{3,2}` gives you `Text with comma, more text`.

Comment: OK, I got textread working. I don't think delimiter is supported:  `Currently implemented PROP arguments are:
    * "headerlines": VALUE represents the number of header lines to
      skip.`

Comment: According to [textread](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Simple-File-I_002fO.html#doc-textread) documentation the script above should be correct and delimiters also should be supported as documenated in [strread](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Manipulating-Strings.html#doc-strread) (which is called by textread).

Comment: @BSeven Maybe you have an older version of octave? I am running version 3.4.0 and the code above runs on my machine.