# Loading text file as a 2D array of strings without specifying the number of columns

Tags: matlab, csv, file-io, octave

Suppose I have a plaintext file `test.dat`:

```
foo bar baz
qux ham spam
```

I know want to load this into Octave (or Matlab if necessary) as a two-dimensional cell array, preserving the structure encoded in whitespace and newlines. According to my understanding of [the documentation](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/textscan.html), the following should be the way to go:

```
format = '%s';
file = fopen('test.dat');
data = textscan(file,format);
fclose(file);
disp(data);
```

However this only loads the data as a one-dimensional array:

```
{
  [1,1] = 
  {
    [1,1] = foo
    [2,1] = bar
    [3,1] = baz
    [4,1] = qux
    [5,1] = ham
    [6,1] = spam
  }
}
```

Explicitly specifying `Delimiter`, `Whitespace`, and `EndOfLine` does not help (what’s the point of the latter then?); neither does using other loading functions like `textread` or `dlmread`. What does work is using `format = '%s%s%s'` in the above but this requires that I somehow identify the number of columns, which the function should be able to do itself.

Thus I ask: **Is there any *built-in* function that does what I want?** I am not interested in ways to write such a function myself – I am confident that I can do this, but that’s exactly what I want to avoid (as I need to use this for demonstrating good practice, and thus not re-inventing the wheel).

Related Q&As (that all work with knowing the number of columns):

- [How to load 2D array from a text(csv) file into Octave?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8513856/2127008)
- [How do I read a delimited file with strings/numbers with Octave?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5301419/2127008)

Comment: If you use `%s` as a format, `textscan` will treat the whole line as one string, so yes you do need to know the number of columns. Your only other option is to scan each line at a time using `fgetl` and then parse the resulting line using whatever separator you have to split each line into separate strings.

Comment: @am304: *If you use `%s` as a format, `textscan` will treat the whole line as one string* – No, it doesn’t. It loads each of the six elements individually; just the arrangement gets lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Octave you can use [csv2cell](https://octave.sourceforge.io/io/function/csv2cell.html) from the package `io`:

```
pkg load io
result = csv2cell('test.dat',' ')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`readtable`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/readtable.html)

```
data = readtable('test.txt', 'ReadVariableNames', false, 'Delimiter', ' ')
```

Output:

```
Var1     Var2      Var3 
_____    _____    ______

'foo'    'bar'    'baz' 
'qux'    'ham'    'spam'
```

If you wanted a cell, not a table, you could use

```
data = table2cell( data );

>> data = {'foo'    'bar'    'baz' 
           'qux'    'ham'    'spam'}
```

I'm not sure that `readtable` is an Octave method, it seems to be [on GitHub](https://github.com/octave-de/table/blob/master/readtable.m) but I have no installation to check. It was introduced to Matlab in 2013b.

---

You could use lower level actions, reading the lines one by one

```
fid = fopen('test.txt','r');
data = {};
while ~feof(fid)
    line = fgets(fid);       % Read line
    A = strsplit(line, ' '); % Split on spaces
    data(end+1, :) = A;      % Append to output
end
fclose(fid);

>> data = {'foo'    'bar'    'baz' 
           'qux'    'ham'    'spam'}
```

This method assumes each row of `data` will have the same number of elements (same number of delimiters in each line). If you can't assume that, then a safer way would be to do `data{end+1,1} = A`, then splitting the lines afterward.

The only function used in this method which isn't low level file I/O is `strsplit`. This is a built-in for [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Manipulating-Strings.html#XREFstrsplit) and [Matlab](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you have a look at fgetl() or fgets() functions.
Basically you read the lines of the file and then you can apply your code with textscan() and get the "columns".

Comment: This does not address my question which was explicitly about not implementing this myself. @Wolfie: This is not a valid comment either (it does nothing comments are for).

Comment: @Wrzlprmft You're right, I've deleted the comment as I planned to, was just trying to help Ari learn how the site works. I've also updated my answer to use Octave built-in methods

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.  readtable.m was slow for me in Matlab, and fgetl examples are resizing in a loop.
But perhaps an acceptable solution is based on this forum post:
https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/476483-how-to-use-textscan-on-a-cell-array-without-a-loop

So, at least in newer Matlab:

```
fid=fopen(file,'r');
data=textscan(fid,'%s','Delimiter','\r\n');
fclose(fid);
data=split(data{1},';',1);
```

I haven't tested split.m for speed with large data though.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add a cell array transpose to bring the data back to col/row shape.